# Get value of IEnumerable without having to hardcode it

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-5

I'm experimenting with adding a Razor page that will display Employees in all stores that belong under the same companies subgroup identifier. If I hard code the value `.Contains("ABC")` in `var employees` then I get a list of persons in that company and its subgroups. If I try to use `var currentEmpSub`, then I do not get my list. I'm not sure what I need to do (add another variable? fix my LINQ query? or something else). Any suggestions would be very helpful! Once I get this I will also do one for a manager view that will show only employees under the managers' store (instead of subgroup).

Setup is a many-to-many relationship with EFCore 5.0

```
public class Employee
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;]

public ICollection<Tenant> Tenants {get; set;}
}

public class Tenant
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;]

public ICollection<Employee> Employees{get; set;}
}
```

**Admin.cs**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            var currentEmp = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.GetUserId();
            
            var currentEmpTenant = await _context.Employees
                .Include(x => x.Tenants)
                .Where(e => e.AspUserId == currentEmp)
                .FirstAsync();

            var currentEmpSub = currentEmpTenant.Tenants
                .Select(x => x.SubName)
                .ToString();
            
            var employees = _context.Employees
                .IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Include(t => t.Tenants)
                .Where(x => x.Tenants
                    .Select(sub => sub.SubName)
                    .Contains(currentEmpSub))
                .ToListAsync();
            return await employees;
        }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Navrae.DataLayer.Extensions
@model Navrae.WebApp.Pages.Admin.IndexModel
@{
}
<h2>Employee List</h2>
<table class="table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Store</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var emp in @Model.Employees)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@emp.FullName</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var comp in emp.Tenants)
                {
                    if (emp.Tenants.Count > 1)
                    {
                        String.Join(", ", @comp.CompanyName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @comp.CompanyName
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IAdminView _adminView;

        public IndexModel(IAdminView adminView)
        {
            _adminView = adminView;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Employees = await _adminView.GetAllEmployees();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the `currentEmpSub` variable? Because calling To**String** after `Select(x => x.SubName)` most probably produces something like "List<string>", not the value(s) you are trying to put there.

Comment: You are right, it did procude a List<string>. I replaced .ToString() with a call for .SingleOrDefault() and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

User @Ivan Stoev pointed out that by calling .ToString() produced a List. While it did not solve my problem it was an unintended side effect. I used .SingleOrDefault() on the end of `currentEmpSub` and obtained the result I was looking for.

**Note you can also use .Single() .First() .FirstOrDefault()

```
var currentEmpSub = currentEmpTenant.Tenants
                .Select(x => x.SubName)
                .SingleOrDefault();
``
```